# Illegal argument exception at Hive 0.14 Startup

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, bigdata, hadoop2

I am getting below exception with Apache Hive 0.94 using ACID configuration. I am using Apache Hadoop 2.6 with Oracle Java 8. Can someone help me by pointing to  the root case and any potential fixes for this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bhive.session.id%7D_resources
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:444)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:672)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bhive.session.id%7D_resources
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:172)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:490)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:430)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bhive.session.id%7D_resources
at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1804)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:752)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:203)
```

Comment: Can you share your hiv-site.xml here ?

Comment: I tried switching to hive-0.13 and now I started getting metastore_db connection error. No idea how to fix it. Have updated my questions with hive-site.xml

Comment: I could not see the Hive-site.xml. Can you check that again ?

Comment: Hi @ASingh how did you finally resolved it ?
Nothing is working for me.... Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

In the hive-site.xml, replace ${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${system:user.name} by /tmp/mydir as what has been told in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration.